# Cannot create invoice in magento 2.2.7?

Tags: magento2, php, admin, invoice, tax

After installation of [Magento 2 GST extenstion](https://github.com/Codilar/magento-2-gst), I try to **create an invoice** from the admin. But it is showing an error: "cannot create an invoice".

[image]

This issue reported in [github](https://github.com/Codilar/magento-2-gst/issues/3)

Comment: what error. what have you tried to solve this?

Comment: @Philipp I don't have much knowledge in Magento. Please find the error screenshot I updated. I think the error may be due to the updated schema of this module(but I will not sure)

Comment: You might want to take a look at `<Magento_Dir>/var/log/exception.log`

Comment: @coderGeek I am didn't get an exception but debug.log I am getting the following error.                                                                                   
 [2019-07-11 18:21:14] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin/sales/order/view/order_id/97/key/114194c961994670cd3e612b6ad2eeca1105cc152bcb55c42403067b516ddf6b/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Comment: Try looking at system.log. If you were able to create invoices before installing the extension, then you might have to debug the extension.

Comment: @coderGeek yes if I disable the module means I can able create an invoice. And also I attached the Github link of that extension above.

Comment: @Arul Did you try changing settings from Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings -> Show Full Summary to -> No.

Comment: @Arul Try switching to developer mode to see what exactly is the error.

Comment: @coderGeek I am getting the error even if I changed the configuration. I am in developer mode only.

Comment: Check error logs at /var/log/{server}/error.log

Comment: @coderGeek I am didn't having any error.log file in the mentioned path.

Comment: It's the file that would have PHP logs. Wherever your server logs PHP errors, check that

Comment: @coderGeek i am getting the following exception.                             
Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'as': The attribute 'as' is not allowed. Line: 266 Element 'referenceBlock': The attribute 'name' is required but missing. Line: 266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i fixed the issue.I changed the following code in
Codilar/Gst/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_new.xml. I changed **as** to **name** inside the reference block.

```
 <referenceBlock as="default">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="gst/codilar/status">
       <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Codilar_Gst::order/invoice/create/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
    </action>
 </referenceBlock>
```

To

```
   <referenceBlock name="order_items.default">
       <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="gst/codilar/status">
         <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Codilar_Gst::order/invoice/create/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
       </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```